# how to using ConfuserEx source code without errors

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, protected, confuserex

i download "ConfuserEx" source code from : https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx

but if i open the project i have 101 error !
how resolve the errors ? i think i have mistake or something else i don't know.

i try fix some error but i can't and i googling for this problem and i don't see i resolve.

some errors :

> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\CompressionService.cs(149,61,149,70): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDnlibDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\CompressionService.cs(149,3,149,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MethodDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\RuntimeService.cs(8,3,8,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ModuleDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\RuntimeService.cs(11,10,11,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TypeDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\RuntimeService.cs(33,3,33,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TypeDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\MarkerService.cs(9,23,9,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDnlibDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\MarkerService.cs(23,20,23,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDnlibDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\MarkerService.cs(37,24,37,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDnlibDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\MarkerService.cs(42,44,42,53): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDnlibDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\MarkerService.cs(61,13,61,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDnlibDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\MarkerService.cs(68,17,68,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDnlibDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\MarkerService.cs(75,37,75,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDnlibDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\TraceService.cs(10,23,10,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MethodDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\TraceService.cs(23,28,23,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MethodDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\THE\Desktop\ConfuserEx-master\Confuser.Core\Services\TraceService.cs(40,21,40,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MethodDef' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: So you are missing IDnlibDef. You should look for requirements in the documentation. I found [this](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/blob/54a47c13f9da0a1841c9196ffbd15ca68879045e/src/DotNet/ICodedToken.cs) in an other GitHub project. Maybe this was mentioned in a NuGet package?

Comment: i try but i have this "dnlib.dll' could not be found"